# How to disable edit their own profile per role?

Tags: 7

In Drupal 7, How to disable the edit profile permission per role? I found the "[Tab Tamer](https://www.drupal.org/project/tabtamer)" module, but this does not apply the feature per role.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is one module called ["UserProtect"](https://www.drupal.org/project/userprotect) module. With this module you can hide edit account, edit password, email from based on user roles and for specific users too.

You can set permission by going **/admin/people/permissions** where you can see **User protect** and you can configure it **/admin/config/people/userprotect** here

**Protected Roles**

[image]

---

**User Protect Module Permission**

[image: User Protect Module Permission]

For example, I don't want to give permission to my Test One and Test Two Users for edit their profile. So, I wanted to hide it from **"Test One"** and **"Test Two"**.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: not sure why, but somehow user still able to change their email and password

Comment: Have you cleared your caches?